# Ubuntu 16.04 not working on my new PC, Intel i5-6600 Skylake with Nvidia GTX 970

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 16.04, intel

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 before on my laptop and I'm trying to dual boot my new PC with Windows and Ubuntu. I had read that Skylake processors only work with Ubuntu 16.04 so I've tried to install that, the installation goes fine but as soon as I restart I am greeted with the Ubuntu background image, no header, only a mouse icon.

I can't do anything with it, I can't open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Also, the message saying something has gone wrong flashes up, I can click continue if I'm fast enough and it goes away, but leaves me with nothing still.

What can I do?

I'm currently using 14.04, but I would like to have the newer version, especially if my skylake processor isn't supported by 14.04.

**EDIT:**

14.04 does that exact same thing, is there something Ubuntu in general doesn't like about my hardware? Or am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Definitely use 16.04.  Look around here for Skylake Nvidia 970, this problem has been answered before.  What did you do when you were "trying" Ubuntu?  Even the "try" gives you full access to the hard disk.

Comment: Every answer I came across for this involved using the terminal, but I can't even get access to that. Unless you can use it before fully booting into Ubuntu. Sorry, by trying I meant trying to see if that works, fully installing it but it didn't.

Comment: One user connected to Intel video out port and it worked. Then installed nVidia driver, so he could use nVidia out port.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely for your hardware, start with 16.04.  The 16.04.1 release should be out soon (now?) would be even better.  The series of kernel parameters mentioned below can be added at the grub menu -- type "e" to edit, follow instructions at bottom of screen.  Add the parameters to the "linux..." line before the "quiet splash" words. Below are Intel options, and Nvidia options, Use only one set at a time, and start out using one at a time, unless you can find a previous answer using multiple options.
  There are six "virtual' terminals available (the GUI runs on the seventh).  From the background you describe, you can switch to a vitrual terminal one by typing ctrl-alt-F1 (F1 through F6 to select which one).  From there, you get a text login prompt.

For UEFI machines (with a black screen grub (grub-efi)  without any
function key options, like the older grub-pc, edit the grub menu and add the below options on the "linux" line, then boot with F10 or ctrl-X.

```
Options for Video problems:

nomodeset
acpi=0
acpi_osi=linux
acpi_backlight=vendor
noalpic

Older Intel video card:
i915.modeset=1 or i915.modeset=0
newer:
i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
i915.enable_execlists=0

video=1280x1024-24@60
video=VGA-1:1280x1024-24@60

To allow Nvidia hybrid machines to boot.
nouveau.blacklist=1

Skylake needs this (15.04...):
i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
noveau.blacklist=1 edd=on nolapic pcie_aspm=force tpm_tis.interrupts=0 
Maybe
intel_idle.max_cstate=1 nouveau.modeset=0

To slow SSDs to allow them to boot:
libata.force=noncq

worked on an Asus F555u 
pci=nomsi nodmraid
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I gave up yesterday and decided that I was just going to have to run Ubuntu on the Intel graphics, plugging the HDMI into the motherboard. Then, when I want to play a game or run Windows I'd have to switch the HDMI to the Nvidia GPU, not very elegant.